# After successful push to heroku, I get an application error. I am using JAWSdb add-on and mysql on my local. Why cant I get the connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, deployment, handlebars.js

Standard express connection

**Server.js code:**

```
    // Pull in required dependencies
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var app = express();

// Serve static content for the app from the 'public' directory
app.use(express.static(process.cwd() + '/public'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Override with POST having ?_method=DELETE
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

// Set Handlebars as the view engine
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main' }));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// Import routes and give the server access to them
var routes = require('./controllers/burgers_controller.js');

app.use('/', routes);

app.listen(port);
```

The connection looks for JAWSdb addon first, if not connect to local
    mysql.

**Connection.js code:**

```
// Pull in required dependencies
var mysql = require('mysql');

// Create the MySQL connection object
var connection;

if (process.env.JAWSDB_URL) {
    // DB is JawsDB on Heroku
    connection = mysql.createConnection(process.env.JAWSDB_URL);
} else {
    // DB is local on localhost
    connection = mysql.createConnection({
        port: 3306,
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'test',
        password: 'test123',
        database: 'burgers_db'
    })
};

// Make the connection to MySQL
connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('ERROR: MySQL connection error -- ' + err.stack + '\n\n');
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connected to MySQL database as id ' + connection.threadId + '\n\n');
});

// Export connection for ORM use
module.exports = connection;
```

I don't think I am missing and dependencies...

**package.json code:**

```
{
  "name": "eat-da-burger",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Buger eating application with Node.js, Express, Handlebars, and MySQL.",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Hussein Fakhreddine",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "method-override": "^2.3.7",
    "mysql": "^2.13.0"
  }
}
```

I get an error saying no such table in the logs. I don't know what that means?

**Heroku Log:**

```
2018-02-24T23:24:22.364961+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-24T23:24:22.653768+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540291+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540306+00:00 app[web.1]:         throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540307+00:00 app[web.1]:         ^
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540309+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540310+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'blmzyk0sphz3yq4s.burgers' doesn't exist
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540312+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:52:14)
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540314+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Query.ErrorPacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:77:18)
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540315+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol._parsePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:279:23)
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540316+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Parser.write (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540318+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol.write (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540319+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:28)
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540320+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540321+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540323+00:00 app[web.1]:     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540324+00:00 app[web.1]:     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540326+00:00 app[web.1]:     --------------------
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540327+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540328+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.query (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:208:25)
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540329+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.selectAll (/app/config/orm.js:34:14)
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540330+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.selectAll (/app/models/burger.js:8:9)
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540331+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/controllers/burgers_controller.js:10:10
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540333+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540334+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540335+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540336+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2018-02-24T23:24:36.540337+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
2018-02-24T23:24:36.547596+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-02-24T23:24:36.547898+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2018-02-24T23:24:36.549079+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! eat-da-burger@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2018-02-24T23:24:36.549202+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2018-02-24T23:24:36.549395+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2018-02-24T23:24:36.549506+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the eat-da-burger@1.0.0 start script.
2018-02-24T23:24:36.549631+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-02-24T23:24:36.559783+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-24T23:24:36.559932+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-02-24T23:24:36.560010+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-02-24T23_24_36_555Z-debug.log
2018-02-24T23:24:36.544178+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=burgerorder.herokuapp.com request_id=1ffcc0a3-fe15-49a7-80bf-dae378355c0d fwd="172.90.83.64" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=18ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2018-02-24T23:24:36.616665+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2018-02-24T23:24:36.619541+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-02-24T23:24:36.604174+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-02-24T23:24:39.573704+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-02-24T23:24:43.233438+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to MySQL database as id 48180
2018-02-24T23:24:43.233475+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-24T23:24:43.233478+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-24T23:24:42.532808+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-24T23:24:42.532838+00:00 app[web.1]: > eat-da-burger@1.0.0 start /app
2018-02-24T23:24:42.532845+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2018-02-24T23:24:42.532846+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-24T23:24:43.889656+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147650+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147675+00:00 app[web.1]:         throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147678+00:00 app[web.1]:         ^
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147681+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'blmzyk0sphz3yq4s.burgers' doesn't exist
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147679+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147684+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:52:14)
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147686+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Query.ErrorPacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:77:18)
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147687+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol._parsePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:279:23)
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147689+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Parser.write (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147691+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol.write (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147692+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:28)
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147694+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147697+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147699+00:00 app[web.1]:     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147701+00:00 app[web.1]:     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147703+00:00 app[web.1]:     --------------------
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147704+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147706+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.query (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:208:25)
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147708+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.selectAll (/app/config/orm.js:34:14)
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147710+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.selectAll (/app/models/burger.js:8:9)
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147711+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/controllers/burgers_controller.js:10:10
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147713+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147715+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147717+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147718+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2018-02-24T23:24:45.147720+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
2018-02-24T23:24:45.162655+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-02-24T23:24:45.163528+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2018-02-24T23:24:45.166236+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! eat-da-burger@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2018-02-24T23:24:45.166533+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2018-02-24T23:24:45.167098+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2018-02-24T23:24:45.167408+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the eat-da-burger@1.0.0 start script.
2018-02-24T23:24:45.167693+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-02-24T23:24:45.183200+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-24T23:24:45.183858+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-02-24T23:24:45.184053+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-02-24T23_24_45_176Z-debug.log
2018-02-24T23:24:45.156737+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=burgerorder.herokuapp.com request_id=7ba6ffb8-2ba8-45f9-9325-f48155fad950 fwd="172.90.83.64" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=50ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2018-02-24T23:24:45.280176+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2018-02-24T23:24:45.261501+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-02-24T23:25:33.215059+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=burgerorder.herokuapp.com request_id=ed4e8e33-a27d-42ae-8797-82918277154d fwd="172.90.83.64" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-24T23:37:19.469262+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-02-24T23:37:21.346733+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-02-24T23:37:22.947106+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-24T23:37:22.947123+00:00 app[web.1]: > eat-da-burger@1.0.0 start /app
2018-02-24T23:37:22.947125+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2018-02-24T23:37:22.947127+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-24T23:37:23.298062+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to MySQL database as id 51410
2018-02-24T23:37:23.298091+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-24T23:37:23.298093+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-24T23:37:23.569144+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

**Adding burgers_controllers.js code:**

```
// Pull in required dependencies
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Import the model (burger.js) to use its database functions.
var burger = require('../models/burger.js');

// Create the routes and associated logic
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  burger.selectAll(function(data) {
    var hbsObject = {
      burgers: data
    };
    // console.log(hbsObject);
    res.render('index', hbsObject);
  });
});

router.post('/burgers', function(req, res) {
  burger.insertOne([
    'burger_name'
  ], [
    req.body.burger_name
  ], function(data) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});

router.put('/burgers/:id', function(req, res) {
  var condition = 'id = ' + req.params.id;

  burger.updateOne({
    devoured: true
  }, condition, function(data) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});

// Export routes for server.js to use.
module.exports = router;
```

### Schema.sql code:**

```
-- Create the burgers_db database --
CREATE DATABASE
IF NOT EXISTS burgers_db;
USE burgers_db;
-- Create a burgers table with the required fields --
CREATE TABLE burgers
(
    id int NOT NULL
    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    burger_name varchar
    (255) NOT NULL,
    devoured BOOLEAN DEFAULT false,
    ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON
    UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    dt DATETIME
    DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON
    UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY
    (id)
);
```

**orm.js code:**

```
// Import the MySQL connection object
var connection = require ('./connection.js');

// Helper function for generating MySQL syntax
function printQuestionMarks(num) {
    var arr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        arr.push("?");
    }

    return arr.toString();
}

// Helper function for generating My SQL syntax
function objToSql(ob) {
    var arr = [];

    for (var key in ob) {
        arr.push(key + "=" + ob[key]);
    }

    return arr.toString();
}

// Create the ORM object to perform SQL queries
var orm = {
    // Function that returns all table entries
    selectAll: function(tableInput, cb) {
        // Construct the query string that returns all rows from the target table
        var queryString = "SELECT * FROM " + tableInput + ";";

        // Perform the database query
        connection.query(queryString, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            // Return results in callback
            cb(result);
        });
    },

    // Function that insert a single table entry
    insertOne: function(table, cols, vals, cb) {
        // Construct the query string that inserts a single row into the target table
        var queryString = "INSERT INTO " + table;

        queryString += " (";
        queryString += cols.toString();
        queryString += ") ";
        queryString += "VALUES (";
        queryString += printQuestionMarks(vals.length);
        queryString += ") ";

        // console.log(queryString);

        // Perform the database query
        connection.query(queryString, vals, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            // Return results in callback
            cb(result);
        });
    },

    // Function that updates a single table entry
    updateOne: function(table, objColVals, condition, cb) {
        // Construct the query string that updates a single entry in the target table
        var queryString = "UPDATE " + table;

        queryString += " SET ";
        queryString += objToSql(objColVals);
        queryString += " WHERE ";
        queryString += condition;

        // console.log(queryString);

        // Perform the database query
        connection.query(queryString, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            // Return results in callback
            cb(result);
        });
    }
};

// Export the orm object for use in other modules
module.exports = orm;
```

**burger.js code:**

```
// Import the ORM to implement functions that will interact with the database
var orm = require('../config/orm.js');

// Create the burger object
var burger = {
  // Select all burger table entries
  selectAll: function(cb) {
    orm.selectAll('burgers', function(res) {
      cb(res);
    });
  },

  // The variables cols and vals are arrays
  insertOne: function(cols, vals, cb) {
    orm.insertOne('burgers', cols, vals, function(res) {
      cb(res);
    });
  },

  // The objColVals is an object specifying columns as object keys with associated values
  updateOne: function(objColVals, condition, cb) {
    orm.updateOne('burgers', objColVals, condition, function(res) {
      cb(res);
    });
  }
};

// Export the database functions for the controller (burgerController.js).
module.exports = burger;
```

It works when I run the server in node just fine. But when pushed to heroku master the app does not work even after successful push. Am I missing something?

Comment: `Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'blmzyk0sphz3yq4s.burgers' doesn't exist` -> maybe the table `burgers` does not exist in the server?

Comment: @acdcjunior I don’t think I need the table burgers in my server...

Comment: Show us the `/app/controllers/burgers_controller.js`

Comment: @acdcjunior I added it.

Comment: See `router.get('/', function(req, res) {      
  burger.selectAll(function(data) {` It appears you are fetching from the `burgers` table.

Comment: I am not sure how to fix this... Do you mean changing the burger.selectAll to burgers.selectAll?

Comment: No... Your code is using `burger.selectAll` which uses the code in `/app/models/burger.js` which is trying to fetch from the `burgers` table in the database. The solution is: create the `burgers` table. (Or remove the whole `burger.selectAll(...` stuff.)

Comment: @acdcjunior there already is a table called burgers. I added the schema code.

Comment: Yeah, but it isn't finding one, that's what the error is showing. Maybe the problem is with the schema. Show the `/app/config/orm.js` and `/app/models/burger.js` files, please.

Comment: @acdcjunior They are added.

Comment: The problem seems to be the db schema you are using. Give this a shot: on `burger.js` change `orm.selectAll('burgers', function(res) {` to `orm.selectAll('burgers_db.burgers', function(res) {`. This is an attempt to use the `burgers_db` schema because it seems this was the one you created (based on the `USE burgers_db;` line at the sql code you posted).

Comment: Still does not work @acdcjunior. I’ll keep researching. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're using JAWS_DB on Heroku, so you'll have to install the Maria JawsDB add-on and then connect to JawsDB and store your tables/schema there instead of relying on the tables created on your local machine...